# С#. Маршалинг массива байтов в структуру - почему строка обрезается?

Tags: c#, строки, кодировка, struct, marshal

Есть бинарный файл определенной структуры:

[image: бинарный файл]

Мне нужно этот бинарный файл преобразовать в список структур следующего типа:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct LogFormat
{
    public byte type;
    public byte length;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)] public string name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)] public string format;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)] public string columns;
}
```

Читаю файл с помощью такого метода `Read()`:

```
public static List<LogFormat> Read(string filepath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        return null;

    var list = new List<LogFormat>();

    using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // 3 - это просто для теста
        {
            var headByte1 = br.ReadByte();
            var headByte2 = br.ReadByte();

            var formatId = br.ReadByte();
            if (formatId != 128)
                return list;

            var buffer = br.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LogFormat)));

            list.Add(ByteArrayToStructure<LogFormat>(buffer));
        }
    }

    return list;
}

private static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    try
    {
        return Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject());
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Первый экземпляр структуры такой, какой ожидался (`name = "FMT"`), а вот те экземпляры, где реальная длина строки в поле `name` была равна 4, *принимали только **3** символа*, а **четвертый отбрасывали** и процесс преобразования шел дальше без ошибок. На картинке показан результат маршалинга данных:

[image: Результат маршалинга]

Ожидалось, что `fmt[1].name == "UNIT"` но реальное значение `fmt[1].name == "UNI"` (смотрите 1-ое изображение - структуру бинарного файла, там красным подчеркнуто `UNIT`).

Я подозреваю, проблема в представлении строки при маршалинге. По факту, мы имеем массив `byte[4]`. А вот дальше что с этим делает Marshaling - понятия не имею. Бинарный файл записывался микроконтроллером, написанным на C/C++ (точно не знаю). Кодировка строк в бинарном файле, как я понимаю, `ASCII`.

**Вопрос 1**: Почему код работает не так как ожидалось?

**Вопрос 2**: Каким способом все же можно правильно преобразовать массив байтов в такую структуру?

Comment: `SizeConst = 4` - если я не ошибаюсь, это 4 _байта_. А в дотнете строки юникодные, по два байта на символ. Задать `CharSet.Ansi`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov он по умолчанию у структур идет. Даже если явно указать `Ansi`, результат будет абсолютно таким же. А вот если `Unicode`, то совсем перестанет работать.

Comment: А нет ли в `name` на конце символа `\0`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так исходные байты опубликованы, а первом случае есть во втором нету.

Comment: Я имею в виду не в бинарном файле, а в поле name в структуре: `"UNI\0"`

Comment: Дайте ссылку на бинарный файл, хочу поиграться с ним.

Comment: @ヒミコ я его обрезал, [вот ссылка](http://www.filedropper.com/tmp_1)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov если я с помощью атрибута пытаюсь получить строку, то строка name будет без символа '\0'. Но вот если сделать так, как указано в ответе, то символ '\0' остается только у короткого `name`, т.е. `FMT\0`.

Comment: Внутреннее устройство строк (string) в дотнете таково, что содержит null (`\0`) на конце. Он не входит в длину строк. Это сделано для облегчения передачи строк в нативные API, которые ожидают null-terminated строки. / Очевидно, маршаллер вынужден в конце `name` вставить null.

Comment: Соответственно, если использовать `ByValArray`, то в конце массива маршаллер не ставит null.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по поводу внутреннего устройства string я бы хотел отдельно почитать материал. Может быть, вы можете порекомендовать источник? Сходу так и не смог найти ничего

Comment: Даже не знаю... Как-то по крупицам собиралась информация об этом. Из разных книг, статей... Посмотрите [Strings in C# and .NET](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня так получилось:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct LogFormat
{
    public byte type;
    public byte length;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    private byte[] name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    private string format;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    private string columns;

    public string Name => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(name).Trim('\0');
}
```

Comment: Решение рабочее, спасибо. Разобраться бы только, что не так было в моем методе :| Разрешите, я правку внесу, чтобы обрезать лишние нули на конце и немного упростить код

Comment: Да, без проблем. Главное - идея. Я так понимаю, так же надо сделать для format и columns.